# Does optimizer.apply_gradients do gradient descent?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

Ive found the following code:

```
# Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):

    # Open a GradientTape to record the operations run
    # during the forward pass, which enables auto-differentiation.
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

        # Run the forward pass of the layer.
        # The operations that the layer applies
        # to its inputs are going to be recorded
        # on the GradientTape.
        logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch

        # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
        loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)

    # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
    # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

    # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
    # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

And the last part says

```
 # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
# the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

# Run one step of gradient descent by updating
# the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

But after Ive looked the function apply_gradients up, Im not sure if the sentence
"Run one step of gradient descent by updating" for  `optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))` is true.
Because it only updates the gradients. And `grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)` only calculates the derivation of the loss function with respect. But for gradient descent calculate the learning rate with the gradients and subtract that from the value of the loss function. But it seems to work, because the loss is decreasing constantly. So my question is: Does apply_gradients do more than just updating?

full code is here: https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/

Comment: The exact definition of the step is done on initialization of the `optimizer` object. Which is not shown in your code. Generally the `tf.keras.Optimizer` object, update the values of the variables given by `model.trainable_weight`, when `apply_gradients` is called

Comment: Also not sure what you mean by "Because it only updates the gradients"

Comment: I mean with"Because it only updates the gradients". Does it only update the new calculate gradients. Or does it  update the variables after it has used output loss function - learning_rate * d/loss like gradient descent does. The full code is here : https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/

Comment: The `apply_gradients` method specifically updates the value of the variables. The gradients are calculated by the `tf.GradientTape()`, which by default watches all variables that are used for evaluating the loss function. As described in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/SGD) for the statistical gradient descend class, the update rules are defined on initialization and evaluated on calling `apply_gradients` [docs of Optimizer-Base class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#apply_gradients)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.apply_gradients` performs **an update to the weights, using the gradients**. Depending on optimizer used it **could** be gradient descent, which is:

```
w_{t+1} := w_t - lr * g(w_t)
```

where `g = grad(L)`

Note, that there is no need to access loss function or anything else, you just need the gradient (which is a vector of length of your parameters).

In general `.apply_gradients` can do more than that, e.g. if you were to use Adam it would also accumulate some statistics and use them to rescale gradients etc.